# Problema com código Assembly para Linux 64

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bits

Criei um código para GNU Asssembly Linux 64 bits bem simples e funciona. Só que ele depois do strip deixa de funcionar. O que pode estar ocorrendo?

### Inicio do codigo

```
.section    .rodata

clear:
    .ascii "\033c\0"

size:
    .int . -clear       

.section    .text           
.globl _start           

_start:

_zera:

    xorq        %rax,   %rax
    xorq        %rdi,       %rdi
    xorq        %rsi,       %rsi
    xorq        %rdx,   %rdx

_apaga:

    movq    $1, %rax 
    movq    $1, %rdi
    movq    $clear, %rsi
    movq    size,   %rdx
    syscall

_fim:
    movq    $60,    %rax
    movq    $0,     %rdi
    syscall
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Ele é um código que usa sequência de escape de terminal (\033c) para limpar a tela (igual ao comando clear no Linux). Ele funciona antes do strip e depois do strip não funciona mais.

Comment: qual é o problema com o código? Aparentemente não tem nada de errado

Comment: eu rodei o código sem nenhum problema, tem algum erro que está dando, como o terminal travado? ou falha de segmentação?

Comment: Não. Ele apenas não limpa a tela depois do strip. Eu sou obrigado a usar o as (GNU Assembler) com opção -ggdb senão o programa não limpa a tela. Depois disso, se eu uso o strip, ele não limpa a tela.

Comment: coloca os passos que está fazendo para a compilação e execução do código

Comment: Assim funciona:

as clrscr_64-001.s -o clrscr_64-001.o -ggdb
ld clrscr_64-001.o -o clrscr_64-001

Assim não funciona:

as clrscr_64-001.s -o clrscr_64-001.o
ld clrscr_64-001.o -o clrscr_64-001

Comment: funcionou dos dois jeitos, verifique a versão do `as`, qualquer coisa tente fazer o código em outra linguagem. o meu está na versão 2.26.0 com o binutils 2.26.0.20160302

Comment: O que quer dizer outra linguagem? A versão é 2.25 no Debian 8 Stable. Quando fiz este código para x86 funcionou. Agora para x86_64 não está funcionando como devido.

Comment: em outra inguagem como C, python, perl, etc. mas se funcionou para 32x e para 64x não, pode ser algum problema com suas bibliotecas.

Comment: Testei no Slackware e ocorreu o mesmo.

Comment: Infelizmente continua sem funcionar. Já testei em dois sistemas diferentes de 64 bits, com assemblers diferentes. Funciona apenas com montagem com opção -ggdb. Sem a opção ou após o strip, o código não apaga caracteres da tela. Funciona imprimindo a sequência de escape "\033c", que é um <ESC> (ascii 27) seguido de um 'c' minúsculo. Essa impressão funciona em outras linguagens e até BASH script.